# segmentation fault while loading libutils.so in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

While loading your library, I am getting error on loading libutils. so I am new to `NDK`, so don't know much.
Error log:

> I/CallRecLib: Error: dlopen failed: library "libutils.so" not found
>   02-06 18:11:12.960 21141-21141/com.superreceptionist
>   W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   02-06 18:11:12.960 21141-21141/com.superreceptionist
>   W/google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint: 02-06 18:11:12.960
>   21141-21141/com.superreceptionist W/google-breakpad: 2.6.2 02-06
>   18:11:12.960 21141-21141/com.superreceptionist W/google-breakpad: 158
>   02-06 18:11:12.960 21141-21141/com.superreceptionist
>   W/google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
>   02-06 18:11:12.960 21141-21141/com.superreceptionist A/libc: Fatal
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 21141
>   (perreceptionist)